# Processing mailed checks where donor sends monthly

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

We have quite a few donors that mail a check every month (probably 80% of our checks we receive). It is for the same amount and project(s). Each donor generally sends their check around the same time each month. I am looking for ideas on how to streamline the manual data entry for these "recurring contributions".

We use Drupal for our CMS. iATS for our payment processor.

1. Is there already a method or extension to do this?
2. Would this be something I could use a View/ CiviEntity to do? I am not familiar with Entity but if you point me in the right direction, I can probably put something together.

Comment: could pledges play a part in this for you?

Comment: You can enter the account details from the cheque to set up an automated monthly ACH (with the donor’s permission)

Comment: @ petednz that looks like we would need to go into each contact > Pledges tab and enter contribution there. Probably more work than what we now do.

Comment: @KarinG we have included a piece with our receipts for a couple months that them giving through ACH will save us time and $. Many in this group of people have told us they are not comfortable with an automatic recurring contribution. They want to mail a check each month.

Comment: I have looked at using Batch Entry but we use Line Items.

Comment: @peterdnz now that I am thinking about it more maybe you were on the right track. If I could create a View for pledges where our staff can interact to process the next pledge.

Comment: Educate them that automatic is way safer! A mailed cheque can be intercepted -> it contains all their bank details -> if it falls into the wrong hands someone could empty their account. There are few protections in place when it comes to bank accounts.

Comment: You're preaching to the choir! I cannot believe that people still hand total strangers a piece of paper with all the details they need to clean out their bank account.

Comment: @peterdnz pledges do not allow for line items

Comment: I had the idea that I could create a dummy payment processor and then make these recurring contributions using that payment processor. But I have not found a way to have it process the checks

Comment: For a client with similar needs I set up a Contributions Search Task called Repeat Contribution. The client would search for last month's cheques, giving them search results with a checkbox by each. They'd check the ones that had been sent in this month, and choose the Repeat Contribution action which would then duplicate the selected ones with today's date. They've not used it for a while (thankfully online now) but I can dig out the code if interested.